# pagecontainer firing events (multi page site)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Ok, Im using JQM 1.4.5 and i'm trying to resolve all the deprecated commands on an existing multi page/file site.

This may appear simple but after spending several hours on google finding several different ideas some of them conflicting i've finally exhausted all options.

I'm trying to replace the existing events [pageinit] and [pagebeforeshow].
According to JQM website I can bind in two ways:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {}      );

$( ":data('mobile-pagecontainer')" ).pagecontainer({
  beforeshow: function( event, ui ) {},
  beforehide: function( event, ui ) {},
  show: function( event, ui ) {},
  hide: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

I've tried:

```
$( "#pageDetails" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {}   
alert("show");     );
```

AND

```
$("#pageDetails").pagecontainer({
    create: function( event, ui ) {
            alert("Create");
        },
        show: function( event, ui ) {
            alert("show");
        },
        beforeshow: function( event, ui ) {
            alert("show");
        }
    });
```

of which the 'create' is fired as expected but nothing else.

On my index.html page I have script outside of the initial pages which runs across all pages and inside each html file I have script inside a page are which relates to each page.

Previously I had:

```
$("#pageDetails").off("init");
$("#pageDetails").on("init",function(){ 
});

$("#pageDetails").off("pagebeforeshow");
$("#pageDetails").on("pagebeforeshow",function(){   
});
```

Both of these fire fine.

How can I convert to the newer method ?

Comment: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/